# Setting up Jenkins with Docker and Bundler

Tags: jenkins, docker, dockerfile

So I seem to be getting nowhere fast when trying to get bundler set up with Jenkins using Docker, setting up Jenkins is fine, no problems there, but I can't figure out how to get bundler accessible

```
FROM jenkins
USER root
RUN gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys D39DC0E3
RUN /bin/bash -l -c "curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby"
RUN /bin/bash -l -c "source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm"
USER jenkins
```

A previous comment in another post has advised `install bundler from the debian package`, but not sure how I would do that or another option would be to add the `GEM_PATH` to the `PATH` variable....

```
RUN /bin/bash -l -c 'export GEM_PATH=/usr/local/bundle' >> $PATH/.bashrc
```

I don't think that's right at all.

The reason I need bundler is that in my post build script in Jenkins I need to run `bundle exec rubocop` and `bundle install`.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with this:

```
$ cat Dockerfile 
FROM jenkins
USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ruby bundler
USER jenkins

$ cat Gemfile
source "https://rubygems.org"
gem "hello-world"

$ docker run -ti  -v $(pwd):/src $(docker build -q .) sh -c "cd /src ; bundle install --binstubs --path vendor/bundle ; ./bin/hello-world" 
Using hello-world 1.2.0
Using bundler 1.7.4
Your bundle is complete!
It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
this is executable hello-world
```

This works for this hello-world example. In your question you're installing rvm. People often do this because rvm allows to install plenty of different ruby versions when your projects are using specific versions.

Note: in your Dockerfile, the `RUN /bin/bash -l -c "source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm"` is totally useless, as it sources the script that sets up the environment to use a specific ruby version at runtime (within the current shell). When the docker image is produced, variables set by running this script aren't set in a container running this image.

Answer (score 0):

My answer to this was adding steps to install rvm also for 'jenkins' user almost in the end of the Dockerfile and then changing back to 'root'

```
USER jenkins
RUN gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
RUN \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
RUN /bin/sh -c export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/rvm/bin" [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]]
RUN /bin/sh -c export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/rvm/bin" -s "source '$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm'"
RUN echo "source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" >> /home/jenkins/.profile
USER root
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, so did you install rvm for the root user and the jenkins user ?

Comment: Yes actually I did